# How to add my 2 radio buttons value in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code:

```
<div id="star-rating">
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $('#star-rating form').submit(function(){
  $('.test',this).html('');
   $('input',this).each(function(){
   if(this.checked) 
  //$('.test',this.form).append(''+this.name+': '+this.value+'<br/>');
$('.test',this.form).append(this.value);
});
 return false;
});
});
</script>

<form name="form1" method="post" action="<?=base_url();?>rate/student">
    <div class="dbtable">

    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tbody>
    <th colspan="4" align="left">Personal Appearance</th>
    <tr><td width="10px"></td><td width="60%">Neatness</td>
        <td width="20%">
            <input name="neat" type="radio" class="neat-star" value="1" title="Poor"/>
            <input name="neat" type="radio" class="neat-star" value="2" title="Fair"/>
        </td>
        </tr>

    <tr><td></td><td>Health</td>
        <td>
            <input name="health" type="radio" class="health-star" value="1" title="Poor"/>
            <input name="health" type="radio" class="health-star" value="2" title="Fair"/>
        </td>
        </tr>
    <tr><td></td><td align="right"></td>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Submit scores!" /></td>
        <td><div class="test Smaller">
            <span style="color:#FF0000">Results</span>
            </div>
        </td></tr>
```

So now I have 2 radio star rating. What I want is when I click the submit score it will add up the 2 selected radio box. E.g when click radio button neat with the value of 1 and radio button health with the value of 2 then the result will show 3 coz 1+2=3 in my div class=test. Could anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#star-rating form').submit(function() {
    $('.test', this).html('');
    var total = 0;
    $('input', this).each(function(){
        if(this.checked) {
            total += parseInt(this.value, 10);
        }
    }
    //Do something with total
    return false;
});
```

You need to use `parseInt` to convert a String into a Number. Otherwise, you'll just be concatenating values onto a string.

Comment: got it working. ^_^. follow up question. in my first question I needed to sum the 2 radio and get its total. Now how can I divide the total with a fix number of 16? E.g 16/total

Comment: @Dean - You want to divide 16 by the total? Then just do what you suggested: `total = 16/total;`!

Comment: haha, got it working. tested it myself. thanks again for the help james. ^_^

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#star-rating form').submit(function() {
    var score = $(this).find('.neat-star').val()
              + $(this).find('.health-star').val();
    $(this).find('.test').html(score);
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
(function(){
  $('#star-rating form').submit(function(){
      var neatVal, healthVal;
      neathVal = $(this).find("input[name=neat]:checked").val();
      healthVal = $(this).find("input[name=health]:checked").val();
      $('.test', this).append(praseInt(neatVal) + parseInt(healthVal ));
      return false;
  });
});
```